# Post to Brand Page Wall from the App (generic) User - not the Brand Page Admin

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall

Is there a way to post a message on a Brand Page's Wall as the User of my canvas or tab app?

I love when a Brand Page has a medley of User Contributed Posts as well as Brand Owner Posts. This has real value for Brands because the Wall conversation becomes more of a Community Hub - rather than a one sided conversation.

There are many articles on stackoverflow about Posting to Brand Page Wall as the Brand Page or as the Brand Page Admin, but I really want the post to come from the average user of my app.

Scenario:

1. I create an app with 3 choices (Red, Blue, Green)
2. We ask the App User to select a Color preference
3. The App Posts the Selected Choice to my Brand Page's Wall on behalf of the App User (with their User Pic, Name, Selected Choice, etc)!

Is this even possible? I understand how to post to the User's Wall - using the Access Token from the user with OAuth extended Permissions of publish_stream , but how can we direct the message to my Brand's Wall on behalf of the user? Any insight is much appreciated.

[mockup of the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOZJs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publish_stream` is the permissions you want to use to http post to `pageid/feed`

Comment: Whooo hoooo!  I got one  :)  Thank you. Someone put me up to trying to answer 5 questions correctly on StackExchange.  This would make my second one if you can mark it accepted by clicking the grey check mark beside my answer.